# Ayuda para algoritmo de optimización combinatoria

Tags: optimización

Mientras trabajaba en un proyecto me he encontrado un problema con un algoritmo de optimización, que quizá es una cuestión más matemática que informática pero espero que alguien pueda ayudarme con ello.

La cuestión (sin entrar al detalle de qué representa cada concepto) es la siguiente: tenemos una area irregular de forma y dimensiones definidas por el usuario. El programa debe entonces realizar un cálculo de optimización combinatoria para cubrir completamente dicha area con círculos, que tienen cuatro radios distintos. La idea es utilizar el menor número de círculos y del menor radio posible.

Alguna idea de cómo enfocarlo? Adjunto imagen para clarificar la explicación.

Gracias

[image: Ejemplo area]